# Having trouble starting with an empty list and adding to it using an input within a for loop

Tags: python

For a programming class at school, I have been asked to do the following:

> Start with an empty coffee_price_list. Use a while loop to ask for the price of a latte or a negative number to stop adding more prices. Inside the while loop ask for a coffee price, or a negative number to stop. Append the positive coffee prices to your coffee_price_list. When done, your program will find how many items are in your list. Print each price from the list, one price per line.

I have gotten this far and I believe I am close to solving the problem, but keep running into problems.

```
coffee_price_list = [ ]
coffee = 0
while coffee > 0:
    coffee = int(input("Enter price of coffee or a negative value to 
    stop: "))
    if coffee < 0:
        coffee_price_list.append(coffee)
for price in coffee_price_list:
    print(price)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: the `if` statement will never be evaluated inside the `while` statement since `coffee` is 0

Comment: Also - you never append any positive amounts... once you've fixed what @eagle has pointed out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this if coffee price cannot be zero

```
coffee = 1 # or any other positive number
while coffee > 0:
    coffee = int(input("Enter price of coffee or a negative value to 
stop: "))
    if coffee > 0:
```

if coffee price can be zero, use this

```
coffee = 0
while coffee >= 0:
    coffee = int(input("Enter price of coffee or a negative value to 
stop: "))
    if coffee >= 0:
```